# python issue while importing a module from a file

Tags: python

the below is my main_call.py file

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

from test_invoke.invoke import end_invoke

from config import config

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/get/posts", methods=["GET"])
def load_data():
    
        res = "True"
        
        # setting a Host url
        host_url = config()["url"]

        # getting request parameter and validating it 
        generate_schedule= end_invoke(host_url)

        if generate_schedule == 200:
            return jsonify({"status_code": 200, "message": "success"})
        elif generate_schedule == 400:
            return jsonify(
                {"error": "Invalid ", "status_code": 400}
            )

    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

invoke.py

```
import requests
import json
import urllib
from urllib import request, parse
from config import config
from flask import request




def end_invoke(schedule_url):

    

    

    headers = {
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
    }
    schedule_data = requests.get(schedule_url, headers=headers)

    if not schedule_data.status_code // 100 == 2:
        error = schedule_data.json()["error"]
        print(error)
        
        return 400
    
    else:
        success = schedule_data.json()
        
        return 200
```

tree structure

```
test_invoke
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── config.cpython-38.pyc
│   └── invoke.cpython-38.pyc
├── config.py
├── env.yaml
├── invoke.py
└── main_call.py
```

However when i run, i get the no module found error

```
 python3 main_call.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_call.py", line 3, in <module>
    from test_invoke.invoke import end_invoke
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_invoke'
```

Comment: Try. `from invoke import end_invoke`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to import file available in the current directory.

So, please replace line
`from test_invoke.invoke import end_invoke` with `from invoke import end_invoke`

Answer (score 2):

Python looks for packages and modules in its Python path. It searches (in that order):

- the current directory (which may not be the path of the current Python module...)
- the content of the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable
- various (implementation and system dependant) system paths

As `test_invoke` is indeed a package, nothing is a priori bad in using it at the root for its modules **provided** it is accessible from the Python path.

But IMHO, it is always a bad idea to directly start a python module that resides inside a package. Better to make the package accessible and then use relative imports inside the package:

- rename `main_call.py` to `__main__.py`
- replace the offending import line with `from .invoke import end_invoke`
- start the package as `python -m test_invoke` either for the directory containing `test_invoke` or after adding that directory to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable

That way, the import will work even if you start your program from a different current directory.